# Query in Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using the retrofit `GET` method. How do I pass a `query` parameter to it?

```
@GET("/datas/")
Call<List<Data>> getDataInfo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answers will be suitable if you want to send one or two parameters only , if you want to send multiple parameters then you can send it like below-

```
@GET("/datas/")
Call<List<Data>> getDataInfo(@QueryMap HashMap<String, String> params);
```

And put data in hashmap like below-

```
 HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("data1", "abc");
        params.put("data2", "50");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to pass query parameter.

```
@GET("YOUR_URL")
 Call<List<Data>> getDataInfo(@Query("YOUR_KEY") String your_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, use this "drivers" instead of "/drivers/"

```
@GET("drivers")
Call<List<Data>> getDataInfo(@Query("data_id") int dtaID);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit use api as below:

GET Method (with parameters):

```
@GET("doctor_review.php")
Call<DoctorReview> getreview(@Query("doctor_id") String Id);
```

POST Method (with parameters):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update_doctor_status.php")
Call<UpdateDoctorStatus> updateDoctorStatus(@Field("user_id") String doctor_id, @Field("status") String status, @Field("type") String type);
```

POST Method with json object as Body:

```
@POST("SocialLogin")
Call<LoginResponse> socialLogin(@Body JsonObject body);

// take below object as reference that will be passed in above post api as body
JsonObject jsonObjectLogin = new JsonObject();
    jsonObjectLogin.addProperty("email", profileEmail);
    jsonObjectLogin.addProperty("password", password);
    jsonObjectLogin.addProperty("deviceToken", refreshedToken);
    jsonObjectLogin.addProperty("Timezone", Utility.getTimeZone());
```